# remove vscode web development - which extension will work for browser (similar to Live Browser)

Tags: visual-studio-code, firebase-hosting

I have a working remote VSCode on ubuntu machine on the Google Cloud Platform. I am using it to develop a web-based application.
I would like to use an extension / or any other technology to be able to see the website and test its functionality at dev time.
I am able to install extensions, however, they are failing because they are missing the basic browser path/support that is usually available. One of the errors that I received is attached: "No chrome installation found, or no Chrome executable set in the settings - used path null" I attached a screen shot[image]

thanks for any reference,
eilalan

Answer (score 0):

I use the Firebase technology and therefore the serving command should direct to any local machine:

> firebase serve --host 0.0.0.0 -p 8787 --only hosting

The default firebase serve command will direct the web app to localhost:5000 which will not be accessible from your local machine.
On your VM make sure that your virtual machine has port 8787 open (check GCP firewall rules for details). you can use any other TCP port that is open on the VM machine.
Access the web up from the machine http://machine_external_ip:port (8787 in my case)